# Is SHA-1 safe for signing ECDHE parameters?

Tags: hash, elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, tls, sha-1

Is using the SHA-1 algorithm insecure for hashing the ephemeral ECDH public key in the `signed_params` structure?

There are some worrying articles about using SHA-1:

- [Phasing Out Certificates with SHA-1 based Signature Algorithms](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2014/09/23/phasing-out-certificates-with-sha-1-based-signature-algorithms/)
- [Gradually sunsetting SHA-1](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.jp/2014/09/gradually-sunsetting-sha-1.html)

My server sends the following Server Key Exchange message for TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02b).

```
TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Server Key Exchange 
    Content Type: Handshake (22)
    Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
    Length: 148
    Handshake Protocol: Server Key Exchange
        Handshake Type: Server Key Exchange (12)
        Length: 144
        EC Diffie-Hellman Server Params
            Curve Type: named_curve (0x03)
            Named Curve: secp256r1 (0x0017)
            Pubkey Length: 65
            Pubkey: 0...  
            Signature Hash Algorithm: 0x0203
                Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA1 (2)  <<<=============
                Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3) 
            Signature Length: 71
            Signature: 3...
```

Should I change it to use SHA256 like server certificate? Or is it safe since it is used to sign the ephemeral key?

Comment: Why would you deliberately use SHA1 today? This is like building a new car with a 20 year old engine design. It still works, but it simply isn't up-to-date any more.

Comment: You could at least configure your server to allow clients to indicate SHA-256 in the right handshake extension, but I would suggest you make sure that it would not result in strongly degraded performance.

Answer (score 7):

SHA-1 is still thought to be secure whenever [collision resistance isn't required](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/6510/13625).

The hash is both used for signing certificates and ECDHE public keys. There's however a difference with regard to collision attacks. It is possible for an attacker to attack the collision resistance with certificates by getting their own certificate signed by a CA. In ECDHE however the attacker shouldn't be able to control the ECDHE public key parameters that are signed.

So, while I wouldn't recommend using SHA-1 in new applications if you can just as well use another hash, TLS is what it is and this kind of a cipher suite is still thought to be secure.

Comment: Thanks.  
I did some more test according to the comments.  
- A server with two certs below was tested.  
    1. id-ecPublicKey/ecdsa-with-SHA256  
    2. id-ecPublicKey/sha256WithRSAEncryption  
- In both cases, cipher suite negotiation was done by "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"  
- In both cases, the server was sending it's ephemeral pub key with "sha1" hash.  
- When I tested another server with the same certs, that was sending  
    1. "sha512" hash to openssl client
    2. "sha256" hash to gnutls client
# So I'll try to find a way to make my server to select sha256/512 hash.

Comment: @wilson, good to know that you *can* get rid of SHA-1 if you really want to, but currently there doesn't seem to be a pressing need if a server doesn't support the extensions in question.